# How to add an arrow symbol or marker to a QGIS legend?

Tags: qgis, legend, flow-map

I'm currently making a map of student migrations in the Netherlands, including a legend. Here's what I made so far:

[image]

I'm sorry for the blurriness on the map. I'm also adding a legend in the top right corner. Here it is up close:

[image]

What I'm still missing, is pictograms of the arrows. The arrows from the original layers are too big, and don't look well in the legend. So I deleted those layers in the legend. However, I'm not quite sure how to add legend items with simple symbols or markers with a text associated with them. I'd like to add two small images of a simple orange and blue arrow without any curves. I would also like to put some text next to it, like “intra-regional student flows” or something along those lines.

**Questions**:

1. How do I add pictograms/markers of simple arrows to the legend?
2. Why does the quality of the print layout of the map seem less good than the quality of the original map in QGIS?

Comment: 1. See QGIS legend patches : https://youtu.be/IL21scLDKOc, 2. Have you tried to modify the DPI number at layout export ?

Comment: @J.Monticolo 1. The video seems helpful, thank you. 2. Not yet, I'll try.